# In an Ember.Select view, how do I get the prompt to display after the bound item changes?

Tags: ember.js

With an Ember.Select view like:

```
{{view Ember.Select viewName="select"
    contentBinding="view.noseNames"
    prompt="Add a Nose:"
    selectionBinding="view.noseToAdd" 
}}
```

When the user selects a nose to add, I'd like to reset the Ember.Select back to the prompt. How do I do that? I've tried set('noseToAdd' null), but it just sets the Select to a blank item.

A full JSFiddle showing the question:

http://jsfiddle.net/tyH8L/4/

---

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view App.PickANose}}                    
        {{view Ember.Select
            contentBinding="view.noseNames"
            prompt="Add a Nose:"
            selectionBinding="view.noseToAdd" 
        }}
    {{/view}}

    Picked Noses:
    {{#each App.noses}}{{this}}, {{/each}}
</script>
```

​

**JavaScript**:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create({
    noses: []
});

App.PickANose = Ember.View.extend({
    noseNames: ['broken', 'roman', 'hawkish', 'aquiline'],
    noseToAdd: null,
    aNoseWasPicked: function () {
        if (Ember.none(this.get('noseToAdd'))) return;

        var noseToAdd = this.get('noseToAdd');
        App.get('noses').pushObject(noseToAdd);

        // HERE IS THE QUESTION:
        // How do I return the select back to "Add a nose:" ?
        // The following doesn't work in the latest EmberJS
        this.set('noseToAdd', null);                
    }.observes('noseToAdd')
});​
```

Comment: What does your `noseNames` loook like? Can you post a complete example, because your fiddle is empty ...

Comment: gah, I forgot to update. Will rewrite the example.

Comment: @pangratz http://jsfiddle.net/tyH8L/4/ , sorry 'bout that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting `selection` to `null`?

**UPDATE:**

This was a bug that has been fixed: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/7a2a14b81aa7adf46c76c272f93c8aff31749582

Comment: yup: "I've tried set('noseToAdd' null), but it just sets the Select to a blank item."

Comment: To clarify for future visitors: the solution is to ''set selection to null''.